# The given key was not present in the dictionary. Which key?

Tags: c#, exception, generics, dictionary

Is there a way to get the value of the given key in the following exception in C# in a way that affects all generic classes? I think this is a big miss in the exception description from Microsoft.

> The given key was not present in the dictionary.

A better way would be:

> The given key '" + key.ToString() + "' was not present in the dictionary.

Solutions might involve mixins or derived classes maybe.

Comment: Of course, you could use the debugger to find out the exactly context, thus finding the key.

Comment: Problem here is that the debugger is not always available, for example when reading log file.

Comment: You are assuming that all dictionaries have a key where `.ToString()` makes sense. I agree in the case of a `Dictionary<string, *>` that it would be a nice addition to the exception description, but it cannot be applied to all types of `Dictionary<*,*>` objects.

Comment: Nope but even if the key.ToString() sometimes would say "Object" it would still work for maybe 90% of the cases.

Comment: @Andreas And what if `ToString` throws an exception?

Comment: @Servy, That can easy be handled when generating the exception description, with a fallback to "The given key was not present in the dictionary." =(

Comment: I think one reason it is not in there is that MS has absolutely no idea what the key is or whether it should be exposed. It could be PII or a secret that should not be logged. The safer behavior is to expose less details when you don't know who is going to see them.

Comment: Agreed: this is incredibly irritating. Even the type name would be more helpful for situations where the exception is thrown in a release build and the stack trace doesn't make it obvious which line of source code the problem occurred on. I despise uninformative exception messages, and I don't find the PII argument particularly compelling. Could be sidestepped with a runtime flag, and these messages shouldn't bubble to clients in any case.

Answer (score 94):

This exception is thrown when you try to index to something that isn't there, for example:

```
Dictionary<String, String> test = new Dictionary<String,String>();
test.Add("Key1","Value1");
string error = test["Key2"];
```

Often times, something like an object will be the key, which undoubtedly makes it harder to get. However, you can always write the following (or even wrap it up in an extension method):

```
if (test.ContainsKey(myKey))
   return test[myKey];
else
   throw new Exception(String.Format("Key {0} was not found", myKey));
```

Or more efficient (thanks to @ScottChamberlain)

```
T retValue;
if (test.TryGetValue(myKey, out retValue))
    return retValue;
else
   throw new Exception(String.Format("Key {0} was not found", myKey));
```

Microsoft chose not to do this, probably because it would be useless when used on most objects. Its simple enough to do yourself, so just roll your own!

Comment: Doing `ContainsKey` then the indexer will cause two lookups in the dictionary. Doing a `TryGetValue` would only be one lookup and you can just use the Boolean output of that to choose your if/else block.

Comment: try test.keys.contains(key) which returns a boolean.

Comment: The problem is that this exceptoin may happen in code you do not own and then it is pain to figure out which key you should add.

Answer (score 19):

In the general case, the answer is No.

However, you can set the debugger to break at the point where the exception is first thrown. At that time, the key which was not present will be accessible as a value in the call stack.

In Visual Studio, this option is located here:

Debug → Exceptions... → Common Language Runtime Exceptions → System.Collections.Generic

There, you can check the **Thrown** box.

---

For more specific instances where information is needed at runtime, provided your code uses `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` and not tied directly to `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, you can implement your own dictionary class which provides this behavior.

Comment: This usually how I run my debugger.

Comment: Hi @Sam, at which point in the call stack do you find this value?

Comment: VS 2017 (v15.5.7) has it as: Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings -> then check System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException

Comment: When it's not your own code, say it's Mysql.Data library's code, you can't see the key.

Answer (score 13):

If anyone still cares in 2021 and **can afford to move to .NET Core**, .Net 5 finally tells us the name of the offending key:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new()
        {
            ["foo"] = new object()
        };
        Console.WriteLine(dictionary["bar"]);
    }
}
```

Will give you:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'bar' was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at KnfTest.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

The same code in .Net Framework 4.8 gives the old dreaded message.

As for those who can't afford moving to Core yet I'm afraid there is no real working solution. Replacing all indexer invocations with `TryGetValue` is cumbersome -not to say absurd. Subclassing from Dictionary is practically impossible. Yes you can declare a `new` indexer but then polymorphism goes out the window as your indexer will be called only when using a reference of the subclass. Finally, creating your own Dictionary wrapper might be a solution but that's again a non trivial process, especially if you want to replicate exactly the Dictionary which implements not only `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` but also:

```
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey,TValue>
System.Collections.IDictionary
System.Runtime.Serialization.IDeserializationCallback
System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable
```

Quite an overkill "just" for an exception message.

Comment: I cannot believe it took this many years for MS to acknowledge this should have been done from day one. It would have collectively saved developer HUNDREDS OF THOUSANDS of hours around the world.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to manage key misses you should use TryGetValue

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx

```
string value = "";
if (openWith.TryGetValue("tif", out value))
{
    Console.WriteLine("For key = \"tif\", value = {0}.", value);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key = \"tif\" is not found.");
}
```

Comment: This assumes that it's expected usage for the key to not be there.  That may not be the case.  It may legitimately be an exceptional case.

Answer (score 2):

```
string Value = dic.ContainsKey("Name") ? dic["Name"] : "Required Name"
```

With this code, we will get string data in 'Value'. If key 'Name' exists in the dictionary 'dic' then fetch this value, else returns "Required Name" string.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
Dictionary<string,string> AllFields = new Dictionary<string,string>();  
string value = (AllFields.TryGetValue(key, out index) ? AllFields[key] : null);
```

If the key is not present, it simply returns a null value.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowed from @BradleyDotNET's anwser, here's the **extension method** version:

```
public static TValue GetValue<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key) 
{
    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out TValue result)) 
    {
        return result;
    } 
    else 
    {
        throw new KeyNotFoundException($"The given key '{key}' was not present in the dictionary.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# 7.0 or greater, you can Use the out parameter modifer to solve your problem in one line, and only make one call to the indexer. It works in c# 7.0 or greater.

```
public TItem GetOrException<TKey,TItem>(TKey key) where TKey : IFormattable => 
    dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var item) ? item : throw new KeyNotFoundException( "Key: " + key.ToString() );
```

You can also opt for the longer try catch block which gives better exception information:

```
public TItem GetOrException<TKey,TItem>(TKey key) where TKey : IFormattable {
    try{ return dictionary[key]; }
    catch (KeyNotFoundException e) { throw new KeyNotFoundException("Key:" + key.ToString(), e);}
}
```