# c# server explorer error : save view failed

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2015

I am a student and currently doing my internship. I am developing a C# application for my internship project. I created a database in MySQL server and tried to connect with C#.

The error show:

Save view failed with following error:
The given key was not present in the dictionary.
Make sure view name is a valid file name.

Please help me to fix this error.

Comment: Try to debug your c# code.

Comment: Are you modifing the mysql database using the server explorer feature in visual studio?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244336/the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary-which-key

Comment: No, i just need to insert and retrieve data from MySQL database. In Data Connections section of server explorer, it is showing the 'x' sign (not connected sign) for my database. When I refresh the connection, the error message pop out.

Comment: Then it is not related to c#, but to visual studio, you should edit the tags...