# KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary (C# Unity ANDROID APP)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I know my title has so many duplicates but i can't seem to find any the same problem as mine . Let me paste my code.

## LocalizationManager.cs

```
rh.eLanguage language = tzGlobal.Instance.OPTION.language;

    string json = StreetUtility.LoadJsonFromStreamingAssets("notice.json");
    if (json != null)
    {
        // Separate only the necessary parts.
        LitJson.JsonData data = LitJson.JsonMapper.ToObject(json);
        json = data[language.ToString()].ToJson();

        notice = LitJson.JsonMapper.ToObject<string[]>(json);
    }

    string path = string.Format("{0}/{1}/language", rh.Const.LOCALIZATION_PATH, language);
    json = StreetUtility.LoadJsonFromResources(path);
    if (json != null)
    {
        // json load.
        Dictionary<string, string> dic = LitJson.JsonMapper.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

        // dictionary copy.
        dic_localization_text = new Dictionary<eTextKey, string>();
        eTextKey e;
        for (int i = 0; i < dic.Count; i++)
        {
            e = (eTextKey)i;
            dic_localization_text[e] = dic[e.ToString()];
        }

        // Run registered localize function.
        for (int i = 0; i < list_localize_method.Count; i++)
        {
            complete = false;
            list_localize_method[i].Invoke();
            yield return new WaitUntil(() => complete);
        }
    }

    Debug.LogWarning("TODO: Loading popup off.");
```

**NOTE:** I have 2 Version (PC Version) and (MOBILE Version) the PC Version is working very fine now my problem is the Mobile Version

**NOTE:** *this is an android application(apk)*

What I am doing here on `LocalizationManager` is that I'm loading the json file from my streaming asset which is the (`notice.json`) but the problem is that on my logcat it has this error

> :KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,LitJson.JsonData].get_Item (System.String key) [0x00000] in :0 
>                                             at LitJson.JsonData.get_Item (System.String prop_name) [0x00000] in :0 
>                                             at LocalizationManager+c__Iterator0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in :0 
>                                             at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (IEnumerator enumerator, IntPtr returnValueAddress) [0x00000] in :0

Maybe you will asked what i am doing . I am doing a `Choose Language Scenario`.[image]

As you can see on the image if i choose Korea it must change to Korea and so on.

And for further information here is my `StreetUtility.LoadJsonFromStreamingAsset` function

```
public static string LoadJsonFromStreamingAssets(string path_with_extention_under_streaming_assets_folder)
{
    string json = null;
    try
    {
        //Android Platform
  #if UNITY_ANDROID

        string full_path = Application.persistentDataPath + path_with_extention_under_streaming_assets_folder;
        WWW reader = new WWW(full_path);
        while (!reader.isDone) { }
        json = reader.text;

        Debug.Log("Loaded Files: " + json);


  #elif UNITY_IOS //IOS Platform

  #elif UNITY_STANDALONE //PC Platform
        string full_path = string.Format("{0}/{1}", Application.streamingAssetsPath, path_with_extention_under_streaming_assets_folder);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(full_path);
        json = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        reader.Close();

        Debug.Log(json);
  #endif
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogWarningFormat("Failed to Load.\n{0}\n{1}", e, path_with_extention_under_streaming_assets_folder);
    }
    return json;
}
```

This line of code has something to do with the error also. I'm pretty sure of that

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID

        string full_path = Application.persistentDataPath + path_with_extention_under_streaming_assets_folder;
        WWW reader = new WWW(full_path);
        while (!reader.isDone) { }
        json = reader.text;

        Debug.Log("Loaded Files: " + json);
```

Thank you very much in advance and I will apologize if you don't understand my english. Please just ask. Thank you again.

Comment: on the `StreetUtility.LoadJsonFromStreamingAsset` .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The given key was not present in the dictionary. Which key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244336/the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary-which-key)

Comment: What was your json string you logged ?

Comment: @PeakCoder what do you mean i logged sir?

Comment: @mjwills hmmm so how can i parse a json file to an android device??

Comment: Debug through your code @TheGinxx009. One of your dictionaries is lacking a value for a key that you are asking for. Imagine you went to the library and asked for a book they don't have. That is what you have done. You either have to ask for the book in a different way (`TryGetValue`) or make sure the library has the book before you ask for it.

Comment: Your code did not load json from streaming assets on android platform, you used 'Application.persistentDataPath'.

Comment: @PeakCoder i tried using `streamingAssetsPath` it could load the json file but the problem is that it still can't change the language . Maybe @mjwills is correct it may have the problem on the dictionary???

Comment: @mjwills I'm already doing it for 2 days but no luck .

Comment: @mjwills please reread my question i editted it maybe it could help you help me?? .

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `language.ToString()` when you debug through the code?

Comment: my `language.ToString()` is set to EN when i click English Button KR when i click Korea Button. Now my Notice.Json i debug it . It is just `Debug Notice.json:System.String[]`

Comment: Hmm this doesn't work `notice = LitJson.JsonMapper.ToObject<string[]>(json);` ??? on android?

Comment: Your earlier comment said that the exception was raised from `LoadJsonFromStreamingAsset`. Are you guessing? Or debugging through it?

Comment: @mjwills I am guessing on that but now i have already a hint that its on this line of scripts `json = data[language.ToString()].ToJson();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll share to you what is really the error here . There's nothing wrong on my

The line of code below is working perfectly . So let me just explain a bit of it by putting comment lines

**LocalizationManager.cs**

```
//Convert the json string into a LitJson JSON Object
LitJson.JsonData data = LitJson.JsonMapper.ToObject(json);
//Take the json sub-object mapped to whatever language is represented by this variable
json = data[language.ToString()].ToJson();
//and convert this sub-object to an array of strings
notice = LitJson.JsonMapper.ToObject<string[]>(json);
```

So now my problem was on my **StreetUtility.cs** wherein i change this line of code:

```
string full_path = Application.persistentDataPath + path_with_extention_under_streaming_assets_folder;
WWW reader = new WWW(full_path);
while (!reader.isDone) { }
json = reader.text;
Debug.Log("Loaded Files: " + json);
```

to this line of code

```
string full_path = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, path_with_extention_under_streaming_assets_folder);

if (full_path.Contains("://") || full_path.Contains(":///"))
{
     WWW www = new WWW(full_path);
     while (!www.isDone) { }
     json = www.text.Trim();
}
else
{
     json = File.ReadAllText(full_path);
}
     Debug.Log("Loaded file: " + json);
```

So i need to put a `Trim()` on `json = www.text.Trim()` because if i don't put a `Trim()` it will cause an Exception saying

> JsonException: Invalid character '' in input string