# How to display external image to rdlc report using AspNetCore.Reporting?

Tags: asp.net-core, reporting

I am trying to display a web requested image in a rdlc report.

What I've done so far:

1. In Report Designer, set the image source property of the image to 'External' in Report Designer.
2. In Report Desginer, set the image value using the following expression:

`="https://localhost:7015/api/imagens/" & Fields!AsignadoA.Value`

2. In my controller, set 'EnableExternalImages' property of the local report object to true; this I've done
   using the following code since said property is not accessible through the object:

```
BindingFlags bindFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static;
FieldInfo field = localReport.GetType().GetField("localReport", bindFlags);
object rptObj = field.GetValue(localReport);
Type type = rptObj.GetType();
PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty("EnableExternalImages");
pi.SetValue(rptObj, true, null);
```

Then next error appears:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'InvalidImage' was not present in the dictionary.
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.get_Item(TKey key)

ITInventory.Server.Controllers.EquiposController.Get(string nombre) in EquiposController.cs

`var result = localReport.Execute(RenderType.Pdf,1, parametros);`

I understand maybe I had to add a parameter called 'InvalidImage' and pass it to the local report, so I did this:

1. In Report Designer, I added a new parameter called 'InvalidImage'
2. In my controller, I added the parameter to a dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, string> parametros = new Dictionary<string, string>();
parametros.Add("InvalidImage", "x");
var result = localReport.Execute(RenderType.Pdf,1, parametros);
```

I don't get the concept of 'InvalidImage' in this context, so I just assigned it a random value ("x"), expecting a new error message would give more clues.

Still, I'm getting the same error: The given key 'InvalidImage' was not present in the dictionary.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Thank you in advance for the answers.

Comment: Based on my search results, this error occurs if you try to access the value that is not available in the dictionary. Adding the parameter would not help to fix the said error. I would suggest you debug the code may help you find the problematic line of code. Further, I would suggest trying to pass the working image URL in the source of the image in your report. See whether it shows an image. If possible check the value of `"https://localhost:7015/api/imagens/" & Fields!AsignadoA.Value`. See this [Helpful Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244336)

Comment: I know the problematic line of code is this: `var result = localReport.Execute(RenderType.Pdf,1, parametros);` because that's what the error says. Execute method has as an optional parameter a dictionary of the parameters to be passed to the rdlc report. I am not using any custom parameter, but the error message is clear that I need an Invalid Image parameter to be passed on. I've searched what this is meant to be, but had no success. So I thought maybe passing a random valued parameter called that way would either solve the exception or give more clues, but that was not the case.

Answer (score 0):

This solution have been working with me to display an image in a rdlc report using `AspNetCore.Reporting`, the solution is converting the image to Base64 string and then passing this string to `DataSource` field (or parameter) and using this field in the report image.

These are the steps:

Converting image to base64 string

```
public static string ConvertImageToBase64String(string imagePath)
        {
            string result = null;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imagePath))
            {
                using (var b = new Bitmap(imagePath))
                {
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        b.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                        result = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Passing this string to a `DataSource` field (or a parameter)

```
            string logoPath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\Photos\\CompanyLogo.jpeg";
            var dataSource = shippingOrders.Select(x => new ShippingOrderCarrierFileVM()
            {
                CompanyName = _configuration.GetValue<string>("Company:Name"),
                CompanyLogo = ConvertImageToBase64String(logoPath),
                OrderNumber = x.OrderNumber,
                ClientName = x.ClientName,
            }
```

using this field in report image

[image]

If you are using a web requested image as you have mentioned, you can use this code to convert it to stream and pass this stream to the `Bitmap` function, it accept a stream also

```
 //Convrting image URL to a stream
            System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URL);
            System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            System.IO.Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            using (var b = new Bitmap(responseStream))
            {...
```