# Using VS2022, I cannot change C# code in debug mode (ENC1002)

Tags: c#, debugging, project, visual-studio-2022, error-code

Any code modification is forbidding me to continue debugging, raising this error:

`ENC1002    Cannot apply changes -- unexpected error: 'The given key 'TSUNAMI, Version=1.0.0.65535, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' was not present in the dictionary.'`

What is this dictionary?
Tsunami is the name of my project in version 1.0.0.

I couldn't find something related to this dictionary anywhere.

Comment: For an explanation of the error see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244336/the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary-which-key and also read about [Dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-7.0) but as this is currently written, without seeing your code that is causing this, we can't say why its happening.

Comment: Thanks Timothy, Tsunami is the name of my project. I just stop the code anywhere, try to add a line of code, and press continue (play button). But the it is not resuming because of the error. I have to stop and restart the application.

Comment: I see.  Sounds like it could a bug in Rosyln - a similar post can be found [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/debug-edit-and-continue-enc1002-without-a-sense-se/1191039).  I would recommend updating Visual Studio if you aren't running the latest version

Comment: Definitely a Roslyn bug. If you can report a problem through VS feedback, with Help -> Send Feedback -> Report a problem, and give us some details of what type of project you're using etc. that would help. Ideally, if you can add a recording of the problem through the feedback tool, that will capture a bunch of diagnostic data too, which should help narrow it down.